# Error "instantiating servlet class" when files moved to another computer

Tags: java, hibernate

My code works correctly on my own computer, but once I try it on my laptop, I get "Error instantiating servlet class" error. I am using Hibernate with JSP.

It is rather a big project, I do not know what parts should I show here.

it says its related to sessionFactory.

Comment: formatting, grammar, typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate had nothing to do with it.

The problem was that when my IDE wanted to build my project, it would't add the libraries I added to my project. It didn't even create "lib" folder in "build" folder.

All I had to do was to check if this folder that I'll mention below, existed, if so, was it full with the libraries that I needed or not. if not I just have to do it myself.

the directory : build --> web --> WEB-INF --> lib